# What's most performant way in iOS to check if a string is one of a list of strings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, performance

I want to see if stringA is equal to any of a list of strings -- string1, string2, string3. What's the most performant way to do the comparison?

Since my comparison list is rather small, I'm currently trying this:

```
- (BOOL) isStringInList:(NSString *)testString{

if ([testString caseInsensitiveCompare:@"string1"] == NSOrderedSame)
   return YES;
else if ([testString caseInsensitiveCompare:@"string2"] == NSOrderedSame)
   return YES;
else if ([testString caseInsensitiveCompare:@"string3"] == NSOrderedSame)
   return YES;

return NO;
}
```

This obviously does not scale well if I have many strings to compare against. I'd prefer more of a method signature like this `-(BOOL) isString:(NSString *)testString inList:(NSString *)listString` where `listString` is a space-separated string of keywords.

Any thoughts on how to improve performance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most performant way is to construct an `NSSet` of the strings you want to compare against and use `-member:` to test. Once the set is constructed, this will be a constant-time test. If you have a space-separated list to start with, you can use

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:[listOfWords componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]]
```

Constructing the set will be linear on the size of the input string. If your set is the same every time, you can construct it once and hold on to the result. To do the actual test you can use

```
[set member:myWord]
```

If the result is nil, your word isn't in the set. If it's non-nil, it is. Note, this is a case-sensitive search. If you need case-insensitivity, then you should either lowercase or uppercase both the list of words and the input word before performing your test.

Comment: Any idea on the performance of using set matching vs rangeOfString?

Comment: I tested the performance of this, and it was not as efficient as just calling `-containsObject:`.  I suspect that `+setWithArray:` introduces some overhead, while `-containsObject:` is also constant time.

Comment: @Harkonian: rangeOfString: is going to be roughly linear with respect to the space-separated list. It's also not as straightforward as Davyd makes it seem, since you have to include the separators (in this case, space) at both the beginning and end of the string, and tack them onto the beginning and end of the word, or you end up with the problem I mentioned in my comment to Davyd.

Comment: @lemnar: If you're constructing the set every time, then no you've already thrown out the performance gains. But if you hold onto the set and re-use it for multiple tests then it's going to be faster. As for `-containsObject:`, if you're talking about `NSArray` then you're back to linear-time lookup. If you mean `-[NSSet containsObject:]`, that doesn't explicitly document how it tests membership, but `-member:` is explicitly using `-isEqual:`. If `-containsObject:` uses pointer comparisons then it's not appropriate here.

Comment: I was talking about `-[NSArray containsObject:]` which is documented to call `-isEqual:` on every object, unlike `-containsObjectIdenticalTo:` which uses pointer comparison.  While that should be linear time, I suspect it relies on the requirement that `-hash` and `-isEqual:` must give functionally equivalent results.  Thus, `containsObject:` can perform a constant time lookup.  I did assume that caching the list wasn't permitted.

Comment: @lemnar: Your assumptions are wrong. `NSArray` never touches `-hash`. It cannot, in this case. `-hash` has the invariant that objects that are equal must have the same hash, but the inverse is not true; objects that have the same hash are not necessarily equal. What's more, even if `-hash` was functionally equivalent to `-isEqual:`, it would _still_ be linear because `NSArray` would have to traverse the entire array of objects and call `-hash` on each one.

Comment: You're right.  Further testing revealed that, of course, `-containsObject:` really does call `-isEqual:`, and is linear time.  If `-hash` were equivalent to `-isEqual:`, however, the array could call it at initialization time, amortizing the cost over multiple calls to `-containsObject:` like `-[NSSet member:]` does.  Honestly, now I wonder if `NSRegularExpression` wouldn't be fastest.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)isString:(NSString*)testString inList:(NSString*)listString
{
    BOOL result = NO;
    if (testString != nil)
    {
        NSRange range = [listString rangeOfString:testString];
        result = (range.location != NSNotFound);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think you have a problem. `[self isString:@"book" inList:@"pen paper bookshelf"]` would return YES.

Comment: Why wouldn't "book" be in the rangeOfString for "pen paper bookshelf"?

Comment: @Harkonian: It would. That's the problem. "book" != "bookshelf".

Comment: This is empirically the fastest approach.  To make it correct, append and prepend spaces to `listString` and `testString` before calling `-rangeOfString:`.

Comment: @lemnar Although I like the NSSet solution a bit better for readability of code, if this solution is in fact faster I'll change the accepted answer to this one. Can you point me to some docs or references that state this?

Comment: The `NSSet` solution is more readable.  It's also the only constant time solution.  Which one is correct depends on your use case.  If `listString` could change unpredictably, then this answer is correct.  If you often search the same `listString`, then you should cache it in an `NSSet`, and get constant time searching.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)isString:(NSString *)testString inList:(NSString *)spaceSeparatedStrings
{
    NSArray *list = [spaceSeparatedStrings componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    return [list containsObject:testString];
}
```

Note: the above will be case-sensative, unlike your example.  For case-insensative, you will probably have to iterate over some portion of the `NSArray`.

Comment: I could always upper or lower both parameters being passed and not have to worry about case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

According to this, containsObject is more efficient than I would have guessed.  Good news.

A binary search tree might be better, but obviously, that would take some work.

Comment: If the NSArray is sorted you can binary search it with very little work. See `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` and `NSBinarySearchingOptions` for more information

Comment: According to what? This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).